# Max bit errors for a certain hamming distances

Tags: memory, error-handling, computer-science, hardware, hamming-distance

Basically, the code set has a hamming distance of 6, what is the max number of bit errors that can be detected?

I can't find an equation to link the two anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A hamming distance of 6 means that every pair of valid code words is separated by changing at least 6 bits.  So for every code word, changing up to 5 bits leads to an invalid code word.  Hence, up to 5 bit errors can be detected.

A related question is the number of bit errors that can be corrected.  This number is 2 because for each word, there can only ever be one word reachable by changing up to two bits.  If there was more than one such word, the two words reachable by changing up to 2 bits had a distance of at most 4 bits and thus not be part of a code with Hamming distance 6.